# In first order logic, how do we normally represent a statement?

Tags: first-order-logic, ontologies

I wanted for an example such as:

Everyone has a mother.

I've seen that it is represented in FOL as: $\forall x \exists y:$ Mother(x, y)

I'm seeing that as:For every x, there exists a y, such that y is a mother of x.

I want to know why isn't the following suitable:

$\forall x:$ hasMother(x)

Which I feel can be said as: For every x, x has a mother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question and comes down to what you want to achieve with the `Mother` entity.

In your first example, `Mother(x, y)` is a [(binary) *relation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation).  That means that you can have as many `y`s as you would like per `x`.  With `Mother` as a relation, you can also make formula that checks whether you have *two* `y`s that satisfies motherhood for `x`.

In your other example, `hasMother(x)` is a [*predicate*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(mathematical_logic)) that can only be *true* or *false*.  How many mothers do `x` have? Impossible to say.  Who is `x`'s mother?  We can't say.

You could also conceive of a `mother(x) → y` [*function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)) that maps an `x` to its mother `y`, but then you can have only one mother, and every `x` needs to have a mother (in the model).

It all comes down to (a) what is a natural representation of "the world" (whatever you want to model), and (b) what you want to achieve (whatever you want to get out of your model).